# Intellij Debugging ? Customize data views for each collections

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Is there a way to customize data views separately for each collection while debugging? The problem I have is, I can only do this universally ( and it affects every collection in scope.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has debug renderers per type, if you can suggest a criterion how a renderer can be mapped to the particular collection, please [submit a request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) and we'll be happy to implement it.

As a workaround you can have multiple different renderers defined and switch between them via **View As** context menu in the debugger panel.

Comment: I think I would prefer binding an renderer to an individual instance of collection. Is there a way to do that? Lets say that I would like to do it myself, what should I do? (marking question as answered since the original question is answered.)

Comment: There is no such feature. If you can suggest a good way how such binding can work and identify the same collection instance on next run, file a request.